# SQLite trigger insert/replace multiple rows multiple tables

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I am attempting to respond to the insertion of a row in one table (A) to create or update multiple rows in a second table (B) based on the values of a third table (C) (which can be joined to the first).

I have the following construct,

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON A
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR REPLACE INTO B (ID, T1, T2, Role)
        VALUES
        (
            ( SELECT ID FROM C WHERE R1 = NEW.R1 ),
            NEW.T1,
            B.T2, -- The existing row's T2
            ( SELECT Role FROM C WHERE R1 = NEW.R1 ),
        )
    END;

Table A has columns ID, T1, R1
Table B has columns ID, T1, T2, Role
Table C has columns ID, R1, R2, Role
```

I have at least two problems with my attempts at composing the trigger

1. I don't know how to reference B's existing values in the REPLACE case, thus the "B.T2"
2. I don't know how to reference multiple columns (R1, Role) from the same row in table C when doing my INSERT/REPLACE in table B.

Thanks for any help in sorting this out.

Comment: Use `SELECT ... FROM B WHERE ROWID=NEW.ROWID` instead of `VALUES(...)`

Comment: You'd better write an answer and accept it! Just to avoid keeping open questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the SELECT so that all the needed values can be named regardless of whether there's an existing row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON A
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR REPLACE INTO B (ID, T1, T2, Role)
            SELECT
                C.ID,
                NEW.T1,
                B.T2,
                C.Role
            FROM C LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON C.ID = B.ID WHERE C.R1 = NEW.R1;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger AFTER INSERT ON A BEGIN
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO B (ID, T1, T2, Role) SELECT
        (SELECT ID FROM C WHERE R1 = NEW.R1),
        NEW.T1,
        B.T2,
        (SELECT Role FROM C WHERE R1 = NEW.R1)
        FROM B WHERE ROWID=NEW.ROWID
    END;
```

Comment: Isn't "FROM B WHERE ROWID=NEW.ROWID" doomed to failure, given that NEW refers to a row in A?  In any case, I cannot make the SELECT work in that form, including a try where I selected constant values.  A trigger with a straight insert of constants using the VALUES form worked fine, but that only verifies my test rig.  I'm still stymied by the two listed problems.

Comment: Why should `B.rowid` be the same as `A.rowid`? And for a newly INSERTed `A` record, `NEW.rowid` will never be found in `B`, so the outer SELECT will not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

To find the `B` record, just use a subquery like you're doing with `C`.
The `B.ID` value to search for is the same as that you're trying to insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
AFTER INSERT ON A
BEGIN
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO B (ID, T1, T2, Role)
    VALUES
    (
        ( SELECT ID FROM C WHERE R1 = NEW.R1 ),
        NEW.T1,
        ( SELECT T2 FROM B WHERE ID = ( SELECT ID FROM C WHERE R1 = NEW.R1 ) ),
        ( SELECT Role FROM C WHERE R1 = NEW.R1 )
    );
END;
```

Comment: That's a step in the right direction, giving me a single, correctly-shaped record.  Now my challenge is to be able to handle the case where  multiple rows are involved from table C - the second problem involved with my trigger.  That is, my test case has two rows in C where R1 = NEW.R1.  Right now, I'm only getting a row inserted in B for the first row in C.  That makes perfect sense, given that the inner SELECTs are only supposed to provide a single value.  So I assume SQLite is taking the first value returned.